# Using filter() to implemnt curriable() in javascript is fial , however, uisng map() is work, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to implement the curry() with placeholder support, that is `curriable`. `curriable` provides a high performance and small footprint `curry` method. The version1 is the working code
is using map in the recursion function. However, I tried to use filter to filter the placeholder in the version2! Using filter is good for most cases, but  fail with case  `curriedJoin(_,_,3,4)(1,_)(2,5)` withe reason `Uncaught TypeError: curriedJoin(...)(...) is not a function`, can any one tell me why?

***version 1***

```
/**
 * @param { (...args: any[]) => any } fn
 * @returns { (...args: any[]) => any }
 */
// function curry(fn) {
//   // your code here
// }

function curry(func) {
  return function curried(...args) {
    const complete = args.length >= func.length && !args.slice(0, func.length).includes(curry.placeholder);
    
    if(complete) {
      args.length=3
      args.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
      return func.apply(this, args)
    }
    return function(...newArgs) {
      // replace placeholders in args with values from newArgs using map
      const res = args.map(arg => arg === curry.placeholder && newArgs.length ? newArgs.shift() : arg);
      return curried(...res, ...newArgs);
    }
  }
}
const  join = (a, b, c) => {
   return `${a}_${b}_${c}`
}

curry.placeholder = Symbol()

const curriedJoin = curry(join)
const _ = curry.placeholder

console.log(curriedJoin(1, 2, 3)) // '1_2_3'
console.log(curriedJoin(_, 2)(1, 3)) // '1_2_3'
console.log(curriedJoin(_, _, _)(1)(_, 3)(2)) // '1_2_3'
console.log(curriedJoin(_,_,3,4)(1,_)(2,5))// '1_2_3'
```

***Version2***

```
/**
 * @param { (...args: any[]) => any } fn
 * @returns { (...args: any[]) => any }
 */
// function curry(fn) {
//   // your code here
// }

function curry(func) {
  return function curried(...args) {
    const complete = args.length >= func.length && !args.slice(0, func.length).includes(curry.placeholder);
    
    if(complete) {
      args.length=3
      args.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
       return func.apply(this, args)
    }
    return function(...newArgs) {
      // replace placeholders in args with values from newArgs
      const res = [...args].filter(element=> element!== curry.placeholder);
      return curried(...res, ...newArgs);
    }
  }
}
const  join = (a, b, c) => {
   return `${a}_${b}_${c}`
}

curry.placeholder = Symbol()

const curriedJoin = curry(join)
const _ = curry.placeholder

console.log(curriedJoin(1, 2, 3)) // '1_2_3'
console.log(curriedJoin(_, 2)(1, 3)) // '1_2_3'
console.log(curriedJoin(_, _, _)(1)(_, 3)(2)) // '1_2_3'
console.log(curriedJoin(_,_,3,4)(1,_)(2,5)) //Fail, because "Uncaught TypeError: curriedJoin(...)(...) is not a function"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add

```
console.log(curriedJoin(_,_,3,4)(1,_));
```

just before the failing line, you'll see that curriedJoin(_, _, 3, 4)(1, _) has already resolved to the string "1_3_4" ...which is not a function.  Hence the error. The two versions behave quite differently (logging the various arg lists during processing is instructive.)  The problem with using the "filter and append" approach is that it's not putting the args in the correct order. For the failing example, after one iteration, the 3rd placeholder ends up at the end of the arg list, beyond where the "complete" test is checking, instead of in the 2nd position where it belongs.  What happens when filtering is that (_, _, 3, 4)(1, _) becomes (3,4,1,_), but the func only expects 3 good args, so this looks "complete" - oops!  When using the "map" algorithm, (_, _, 3, 4)(1, _) becomes (1, _, 3, 4) which is clearly incomplete, so it goes into another recursion level as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `.sort` involves comparison of argument *values* and will not apply arguments with respect to their applied *positions*. Use of `args.length = 3` will support only functions with 3 parameters.

Adding parameter `n = f.length` supports currying of fixed-arity functions as well as variadic functions. Adding `curry.merge` with sound inductive reasoning simplifies merging arguments and reduces complexity of `curry`.

```js
function curry(f, n = f.length) {
  return function loop(...args) {
    const a = args.slice(0, n)
    return a.some(v => v === curry.placeholder)
      ? (...b) => loop(...curry.merge(a, b))
      : f(...a)
  }
}
curry.placeholder = Symbol("curry.placeholder")
curry.merge = (l, r) =>
  l.length == 0 && r.length == 0
    ? []
  : l.length == 0
    ? r
  : r.length == 0
    ? l
  : l[0] === curry.placeholder
    ? [r[0], ...curry.merge(l.slice(1), r.slice(1))]
  : [l[0], ...curry.merge(l.slice(1), r)]

const _ = curry.placeholder

const add = curry((a,b,c) => a + b + c)
console.log(add(1, 2, 3))             // 6
console.log(add(_, 2)(1, 3))          // 6
console.log(add(_, _, _)(1)(_, 3)(2)) // 6
console.log(add(_,_,3,4)(1,_)(2,5))   // 6

const foo = curry(console.log, 3)
foo(1, 2, 3)             // 1 2 3
foo(_, 2)(1, 3)          // 1 2 3
foo(_, _, _)(1)(_, 3)(2) // 1 2 3
foo(_,_,3,4)(1,_)(2,5)   // 1 2 3
```

Maybe a better name for `curry` is `partial` as the technique you are using here is more closely related to [Partial Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).